# Нужна ли здесь запятая

Tags: пунктуация

В случае регистрации нового лица(,) следует щелчком мыши...

Comment: @freelanSER, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, нет оснований для ее постановки. Это необособленное обстоятельство в основном сообщении (для регистрации нового лица).

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение.